# No data dump and low daily-cap API: Can it be called Open Data?

Tags: open-definition

Imagine a service that claims all of its data is Open Data, but:

- Data dumps are not available
- Data is huge
- The only way to get data is the API, which is limited to 50 requests per day (0.001% of total)
- Using several API keys for the same project/endeavour is forbidden and frowned upon

Seeing it branded as Open Data (BY-NC-SA), many people are contributing new items, at a faster rate than 50 per day.

**Question:** Can this be called Open Data?
Or does the idea of Open Data somehow require that it is possible to download the whole data without resorting to subterfuges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote from the [Open Definition v2.0](http://opendefinition.org/od/):

> **1.2 Access**
>
> The work shall be available as a whole and at no more than a reasonable one-time reproduction cost, preferably downloadable via the Internet without charge. […]

So no, what you describe is not Open Data according to the Open Definition.

Comment: Though there are examples of data derived from open data that have limits. One I can think of is OSM's [Tile usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy "Tile usage policy") which is there to prevent the volunteer-run servers from overloading.